# search in json tree node js

Tags: javascript, search

I have a json object. I need to find  the string where yes=1 and get the info about it (name,yes....). How to do it in node js?

```
{"1": {"name":'alex',
      "yes":'1'},
"2": {"name":'andy',
      "yes":'0'}}
```

or is there any way to make a search in objects like mysql does?

Comment: Another question, what do you expect for the result? You want to get the first one that matches the condition, or you want an array of objects that match the condition?

Comment: @fuyushimoya I want to find all the objects with yes=1 and then to use its "name", "yes" and other data as well

Comment: @fuyushimoya return an array with both item. would be thankful for both variants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want to check against same-level properties (ie. no nested objects that you want to recursively search as well), you can use a simple `for-in` loop and directly examine the property values.

```
var obj = {
           "1": { 
                  "name":'alex',
                  "yes":'1'
                },
           "2": {
                  "name":'andy',
                  "yes":'0'
                }
          };

var results = {};

for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key].yes === "1"){
        results[key] = obj[key];
    }
}

console.log(results); // {"1": { "name": "alex", "yes": "1" }}
```

Comment: @Андрей_-_ Weird, I just copy-pasted into the console and it seems to work fine. What was your output?

Comment: I'm getting the object from file and JSON.parse it

Comment: @Андрей_-_ Then the only change is that instead of binding `obj` to an object literal, you bind it to the return value of `JSON.parse`. Something like `var obj = JSON.parse(json_str);`. It generally helps if you share your output, errors and all.

Comment: I got {"numb": { "name": "alex", "yes": "1" }} how to get name and yes if I do not  know "numb" (1 or 2....) ?

Comment: You've lost me. If you got a "numb" key in the result object, that means the "numb" key existed in the JSON, so it is indeed a correct search result. You can access the nested object by using `obj.numb` or `obj["numb"]`. That is, *it has no numeric value; it is a string*. If the "numb" was your own notation of *some number*, then you can loop through the keys in the result object with another `for-in` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want vanilla javascript, below should also work on `node.js`.

```js
var testObj = {
  "1": {
    "name":'alex',
    "yes":'1'
  },
  "2": {
    "name":'andy',
    "yes":'0'
  }, 
  "3": {
    "name": 'bvvpp',
    "yes": '1'
  }
};

function covertCheckFunc(checker) {
  return function convertChecker(target) {
    var key;
    for (key in checker) {
      if (!target.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        continue;
      }
      // Single level
      if (typeof target[key] === 'undefined' ||
          target[key] !== checker[key]) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
}

// Get the first matched item. Return `null` if none match.
function getFirstMatch(checkObj, checker) {
  
  // Convert a object to match to a match function.
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(checker) !== '[object Function]') {
    checker = covertCheckFunc(checker);
  }

  var key;
  for (key in checkObj) {
    if (checkObj.hasOwnProperty(key) && 
        checker(checkObj[key])) {
      return checkObj[key];
    }
  }

  return null;
}

// Get array of matched item. Return empty array if none match.
function getArrayMatch(checkObj, checker) {
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(checker) !== '[object Function]') {
    checker = covertCheckFunc(checker);
  }
  var keys = Object.keys(checkObj);
  var arrayForm = keys.map(function(key) {
    return checkObj[key];
  });

  return arrayForm.filter(checker);;
}

console.log(getFirstMatch(testObj, {"yes": '1'}));
console.log(getArrayMatch(testObj, {"yes": '1'}));
```

If you accept some libs like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/), it can be even simpler:

```js
var testObj = {
  "1": {
    "name":'alex',
    "yes":'1'
  },
  "2": {
    "name":'andy',
    "yes":'0'
  }, 
  "3": {
    "name": 'bvvpp',
    "yes": '1'
  }
};

var condition = {
  "yes": '1'
};

var firstMatch = _.findWhere(testObj, condition);
var arrayMatch = _.filter(testObj, function(item) {
  return _.isMatch(item, condition);
});

console.log(firstMatch);
console.log(arrayMatch);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```